# Read ".wav" file into java android As input file of ".tflite" model

Tags: java, python, android, wav, tensorflow-lite

I have a `Classification` problem in `Machine Learning`. I trained **My Audio** files with a model using `Keras` in `Python`. I did some **preprocessing** on my data (divided into multiple equal segments and then re-sample each of them), then read **left channel** of it (My data were stereo and i used one of channels) using `wavfile` library from `scipy.io`. 
After training with a `1D Convolutional Neural Network`, i saved my model as `.h5` file. After that, i converted my model into `Tensorflow Lite` model (`.tflite`).

In My android project, I putted `labels.txt` and `Mymodel.tflite` into `assets` folder and according to **TensorFlow Lite** Documentation, i tried to run `TensorFlow Lite Interpreter`.

**Here is My question :**

> How can i prepare input data for interpreter which is compatible with python libraries i used when i wanted to train my model ?

**Here is my Python and Java code :**

In this code i segment my audio file:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("audio.wav")
chunk_length_ms = 10 * 1000 # pydub calculates in millisec
chunks = make_chunks(song, chunk_length_ms) # Make chunks of ten sec

for j, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk = chunk.set_frame_rate(16000)
    chunk.export(chunk_name, format="wav")
```

Then, this is part of code where i read the `wav` file:

```
fs, data_s = wavfile.read(file_path)       
data = data_s[:, 0]
```

convert keras model to tflite model :

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('mymodel.h5')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("Mymodel.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

And finally, the Java code:

```
try (Interpreter interpreter = new 
      Interpreter(loadModelFile(MainActivity.this))) {
          interpreter.run(audioBytes, loadLabelList(MainActivity.this));
     } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The main problem is producing `audioBytes` for input of `run` method. If you had any experience about this problem, share with me.